# Solr Atomic update change field name

Tags: solr, atomic

I am new to Solr. I tried to do Atomic update, the .json update file not only changing field values, but field name also has become "fieldname.set", for instance, "price" become "price.set".
Any help will be appreciated.

```
    # /usr/local/solr/bin/solr version
    8.5.1

    # curl http://localhost:8983/solr/books/select?q=id%3A0371558727
    "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"0371558727",
        "price":19.0,
        "_version_":1667214802265571328}]
    }

    # cat test.json
    [
    {"id":"0371558727",
     "price":{"set":19.95}
    }
    ]

    # /usr/local/solr/bin/post -p 8983 -c books test.json

    # curl http://localhost:8983/solr/books/select?q=id%3A0371558727
    "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"0371558727",
        "price.set":[19.95],
        "_version_":1667214933776924672}]
    }
```

Comment: the `post` tool is probably posting the JSON file directly to the JSON update handler, which maps the JSON document to an internal structure where `.` separates each level of the hiearchy. Try to explicitly post it to the regular `/update` endpoint with curl instead: `curl http://localhost:8983/solr/books/update -d '[{"id":"0371558727", "price":{"set":19.95}}]'`

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for your reply. post it to /update works well but I have several millions of records, I can't update by calling curl several million times, that will be extremely slow.

Comment: You can batch updates to `/update` - there is no need to submit requests only referencing a single document. I've added an example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solr-user mailing member have a good solution for this, adding "-format solr" to /bin/post

```
bin/post -format solr -p 8983 -c books test.json
```

Answer (score 0):

The post tool is posting the JSON file directly to the JSON update handler, which maps the JSON document to an internal structure - where `.` separates each level of the hierarchy.

Instead format the update properly and post it to the regular `/update` endpoint with curl:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/books/update -d '[
  {"id":"0371558727", "price":{"set":19.95}}
]'
```

You do not have to issue these calls one at a time, you can batch them into several updates for each HTTP request:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/books/update -d '[
  {"id":"0371558727", "price":{"set":19.95}},
  {"id":"0371558728", "price":{"set":14.95}},
  {"id":"0371558729", "price":{"set":12.95}},
  {"id":"0371558726", "price":{"set":16.95}}
]'
```

After issuing the update you might have to issue a commit - either by including `?commit=true` in the URL when submitting, or if doing batch updates - after you've submitted all the updates to the index by making an explicit commit (for example by only calling the URL with `?commit=true` without any documents attached).

Comment: Thanks! I found another solution, by adding "-format solr " to /bin/post